# Comparing success ratio based on unequal distribution of samples

Tags: r, modeling

I wish to compare the success ratio of offers according to the day of the week.
Here is a table with the last column giving the average success ratio across all offers for that weekday. It *seems* that Mondays are performing the best (0.33 success ratio)

```
tab = table(t$weekday,t$repeater)
cbind(tab, tab[,2]/(tab[,1]+tab[,2]))
             f    t SuccessRatio         
Friday    3806 1359 0.26
Monday    4829 2426 0.33   <--- highest success ratio on Mondays
Saturday  3886 1388 0.26
Sunday    3015 1241 0.29
Thursday  4204 1572 0.27
Tuesday   4390 1929 0.31
Wednesday 5645 2034 0.26
```

My problem is that the offers were not equally distributed across the day of the week. So for example if the offer 1221663 was very successful (whatever the weekday) and was proposed a lot on mondays, this could mislead us to believe that mondays are good to propose offers in general.

Here is an extract of the offers distribution across weekdays:

```
tab = table(t$weekday, t$offer)
tab

            1219903 1220502 1220503 1221658 1221663 1221665 1221666 1221667 1230218
  Friday          2      43      93     305     369      62      21     308     286
  Monday          3      81      90     105     147      20      11     146     144
  Saturday        1      33      78     264     323      67      33     250     275
  Sunday          6      29      71     201     268      55      29     229     209
  Thursday        1      51     101     306     431      72      38     377     317
  Tuesday         6     100      95      80     113      22       7      91       0
  Wednesday       2      82      76      69      91      17       5      65     394
                  etc (only extract of data here)
```

Is there a statistical technique to somehow create a more equally weighted subset of the data in order to have a more realistic weekday success ratio ?

Comment: Have you got any way of comparing the characteristics of the different offers, like variables that describe their features?

Comment: @Deathkill14 Yes I have, but how would other characteristics help me compare weekdays?

Answer (score 1):

You could attempt to address this problem using *matching*. To motivate this approach, [here is a quote about it from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propensity_score_matching) about how bias can arise when observational data lacks the characteristics of a randomized trail.

> The possibility of bias arises because the apparent difference in outcome between these two groups of units may depend on characteristics that affected whether or not a unit received a given treatment instead of due to the effect of the treatment per se. In randomized experiments, the randomization enables unbiased estimation of treatment effects; for each covariate, randomization implies that treatment-groups will be balanced on average, by the law of large numbers. Unfortunately, for observational studies, the assignment of treatments to research subjects is, by definition, not randomized. Matching attempts to mimic randomization by creating a sample of units that received the treatment that is comparable on all observed covariates to a sample of units that did not receive the treatment.

It seems to me, you are concerned by precisely this possibility. Namely, that offers were not assigned randomly across days of the week, and this may end up biasing your analysis. One approach for addressing this problem is propensity score matching. It matches observations from the different groups (the days) so that they are more comparable to each other, thereby hopefully avoiding the effect of non-random treatment assignment. You can find a nice introduction in [Mostly Harmless Econometrics](http://egei.vse.cz/english/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/mostly+harmeless+econometrics.pdf). I am not sure how easy it will be to do matching across all days (you'll have to look into that), but you can certainly compare between two days like this. So if you are particularly interested in comparing other days to Monday, since it seems like a big performer, that should be possible.

You should match on the characteristics of the offers that you have - the idea is that responses to similar offers should be matched and compared to each other.
Propensity score matching can be carried out in R using the [MatchIt package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MatchIt/MatchIt.pdf).

Comment: They clearly have repeated measures. How does that play into the matching approach?

Comment: @Roland This is a good point. I put my answer on hold, so to speak, while I think about this. I will try to address it. Thanks.